# Systemd service sits in continuous reboot on start but works fine on manual start

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, service

We have an application that at one point worked on one of our ubuntu VMs. Recently, it has shut down. I noticed that the application, when i execute `systemctl start application`, it starts normally, begins the application boot stage properly, then abruptly stops, then restarts, then stops, and so forth in the same cycle.

What's interesting is, if i disable the service, `systemctl disable application.service`, then manually `sudo into the application user`, and `run the application manually`, it works fine.

I cannot determine for the life of me why in systemd it won't work, but using the exact same arguments on a manual command it works just fine.

Here's my service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Application
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/application/application/application start
ExecStop=/home/application/application/application stop
Type=simple
PIDFile=/home/application/application/tmp/application.pid
User=application
WorkingDirectory=/home/application/application
#TimeoutStartSec=3600
TimeoutStartSec=500
#Restart=always
#RestartSec=5

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

There aren't even any relevant logs, it just says on `syslog`

```
Starting Application...
Stopping Application...
```

At this point, i think its something beyond the application service that's causing a reboot, maybe an issue with systemd internally.

***I really don't know what to do at this point for diagnosis and root cause***

Any help of what to investigate or a possible solution would be great.

Comment: Note that `network.target` (your `After=`) only signifies that “network functionality is available” in some vague sense, not necessarily that the system is “online”. You might want `network-online.target` instead, though that can require enabling some additional services; see https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/NetworkTarget.

Comment: What happens if you disable the service, but then start it manually with `systemctl start application.service` instead of sudoing into the user and directly running the command?